# Ear training Software

Tags: windows, music

I am looking for a (music) ear training program.

What I (mostly) need is:

- Interval Training
- Chord Progression Training
- Rhythm Training

I am looking a free or rather cheap on for Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ive been using [Auralia](http://www.risingsoftware.com/auralia/) for years now as both a student and a teacher and have found it fantastic.  It covers all those topics and much more. My students love it and their progress speaks for itself.  It's certainly not free, but well worth the cost.  The developers have also started releasing a suite of single topic apps for ipad/iphone.